# How to setup LWJGL with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl

Im unable to successfully add proper dependencies for LWJGL in maven project. I have copied lwjgl dependency tempalte from maven repository, added it to my pom.xml and tried to run basic application from lwjgl.org, without success.

Below you have my pom.xml file, unfortunately when I try to run my first application i get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: lwjgl.dll

I found some sollution that I need to download all jars and attach them as jar library, so I did. File > Project Structure > Librarires > added folder which store all jars for LWJGL, unfortunately this is still not working.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lwjgl/lwjgl-opengl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>java3d</groupId>
    <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please go to https://lwjgl.org/customize, select a variant ("Release" or "Early Access"), select "Mode" = "Maven", select all your needed/wanted modules and simply copy/paste the produced pom.xml snippet.

Note that the pom.xml snippet presented on the website is *not* a *complete* pom.xml. You still have to provide the surrounding `<project>` XML element and additional needed XML child elements.

Comment: So just to clarify, once I add the dependencies to my `pom.xml` file I will no longer need to use the .jar library files?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the IntelliJ Idea IDE for this explanation.

Go to https://lwjgl.org/customize, select a version (Release, Stable, or Nightly), select "Mode" = "Maven". I personally chose "Getting Started" for the modules but you can choose base on your needs. Now press "copy too clipboard" to copy the pom.xml file.

Now open up IntelliJ and create a new project. Select Maven Project and follow the creation of the program. I called mine "maven-test". Copy and paste the script (pom.xml) from the lwjgl website that you have in your clipboard and past it before the `</project>`.

Also copy and paste this inside of the

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

This will prevent an error because of the default Maven compiler which is v1.5

Make a new java class under maven-test/src/main/java called Hello World and paste in the code found at https://lwjgl/guide

Finally press the Maven button on the right of the IntelliJ IDE Editor and press the refresh button that says "Re-import All Maven Projects". Right click insideHelloWorld.java and press run 'HelloWorld.main()'